# Using Taucs or Umfpack in iphone to solver Ax = B

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have a sparse matrix A store in compress row storage ( CRS ) and vector B.And i wanna solve the equation `Ax = B.I` try to using `Taucs` and `Umfpack` but i can not compile in `xcode` project.There are a lot of error.

Comment: Sorry.I mean anyone can show me the way to using Taucs or Umpack in iphone project.When i copy source code of Taucs and Umpack in xcode there are alot kind of error.